# Numpy Array of Strings, Unable to Convert to Float

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I'm having a weird issue with some of my code and I don't know how to get around it. I'm running the same code across multiple data sets, but for certain ones, a key parameter does not convert to a numpy array of floats properly. Here's an example.

```
x_e = ('1.2e+1', '1.1e+1', '9.3e+0', '1.2e+1', '9.5e+0') # raw data is outputted in this format
```

where `type(x_e)` is a `tuple`, while `type(x_e[0])` is a `str`. I need to convert the values to a numpy array of floats. So, I do:

```
x_e1 = np.array(x_e).astype('float')
```

I've also tried `.astype(np.float)`. For 80% of my datasets, this works. For the other 20%, I get this error:

```
In [53]: x_e3 = x_e1.astype(np.float)
--------------------------------------------------
ValueError       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-6fdd73772fd3> in <module>()
----> 1 x3 = x1.astype(np.float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

To circumvent this, I found Numpy's [fromstring()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) function. This takes care of the `ValueError` issue, but something different happens. When applying it to `x_e`, I get the following:

```
x_e1 = np.array(x_e)
x_e2 = np.fromstring(x_e1, dtype=float)

In [60]: x_e2
Out[60]: 
array([  9.76118064e-313,   2.14321575e-312,   1.03977794e-312,
         9.76118064e-313,   2.14321575e-312,   1.03977794e-312,
         9.76118064e-313,   2.14321575e-312,   1.01855798e-312,
         9.76118064e-313,   2.14321575e-312,   1.03977794e-312,
         9.76118064e-313,   2.14321575e-312,   1.01855798e-312])
```

The values are **VERY** different. I have two questions here:

1. How can I convert `x_e` to a list of floats?
2. why doesn't `np.fromstring()` work here?

Note that in my example, `.astype()` works, but in my data, it does not. The only difference I can see between my real data and the example is the dtype and the number of decimal places. Here;s a snippet of my real data after I convert it to a numpy array.

```
In [52]: x_e1
Out[52]: 
array(['1.00166e+01', '1.00146e+01', '1.00046e+01', ..., '1.00066e+01',
       '9.99456e+00', '1.00106e+01'], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

I hope the answer is something dumb, but I'm stumped as to what is happening here.

Comment: Hi @NoVa, tuples are immutable...

Comment: Debug as follows: (1) find an array that won't convert with astype (2) binary search until you find the offending element. Knowing why it fails will get you a long way to figuring out how to fix it.

Comment: What comes after `ValueError: could not convert string to float: `?

Comment: `np.array(x_e, float)` is a more compact way of doing the conversion.  But you haven't found out what string(s) can't be converted.  Effectively `np.array` applies the Python `float` function to each string.  That function is pretty flexible, but has its limits, including some variations on scientific notation.

Comment: I don't see why you are trying `fromstring`.  Did  you even read the docs?  It's input is supposed to be ONE string, not an array of strings.  If `astype` works for 80% of the array then the basic approach is right.  There must be one or more strings that aren't convertible.  Focus on that, rather than trying random alternatives.